# Set Turtle to Specific Grid Location - NetLogo

Tags: arrays, grid, location, netlogo, points

I have seen similar questions but haven't found what I needed yet...
Was wondering if anyone knew how to set specific locations for turtles at NetLogo Setup?

Currently tried:

> to setup

> create-turtles 5

> set turtles at-points [[-12 20 ] [-11 19] [-12 18 ] [-18 18 ] [-11 17]]

but they're all showing up at [0 0]

Thanks!

Comment: `at-points` is only useful for querying the current locations of agents. It isn't useful for changing their locations.

Comment: You probably got an error message like “this isn’t something you can use ‘set’ on”.   As a general rule, when you want turtle to do something, you have to “ask” them. There’s an implied “ask” built into create-turtles, and sprout.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in many ways:

- You can use `setxy` in the `create-turtles` command block. In most models you will see this is used in combination with `random-xcor` and `random-ycor` to give each turtle a random location, but you can also use it in any other way.
- You can use `move-to` to ask a specific turtle or group of turtles to go to a specific agent (e.g. to a specific patch).
- You can use `sprout` to directly ask a specific patch or group of patches to create turtles there.

In any case, I suggest you take a look at the [NetLogo Programming Guide](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html) and the [NetLogo Dictionary](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html)